# Android Controlling Checked Checkboxes in TableLayout

Tags: android, checkbox, dynamic, tablelayout

I have a TableLayout and I'm adding rows dynamically. And in every row, I have a checkbox also.

My problem is controlling which checkboxes are checked and I don't know even how can I loop for each row. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Checkbox checkbox;

checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

checkBox.setChecked(false);
```

or true. that should work, just replace checkbox with your variable and @+id

EDIT:

You can implement OnCheckedChangeListener, then use something like

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.checkbox1:
         if (checkbox1.isChecked()){
        //code to use when user checks the box
        }else{
        //code to use when user UNchecks the box
        }
    break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but my problem is that for each row I want to control if checkboxes are checked. For example in a button click event. How can I do that?